# Rewrite URL with request variable using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Please help me. I need to rewrite this url

`http://example.com/topusers.php?sort=post_count&time=month`

into this style

`http://example.com/top/post_count/month`

I'm using this in .htaccess but when I visit `example.com/top`, it shows 404 Not Found.

`RewriteRule ^top/([^/.]+)?/?(.*)$ topusers.php?sort=$1&time=$2`

It needs to be accessible via `example.com/top` too, because I've set default values if `sort` and `time` are not set via URL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're requring slash after `top` in your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^top/?([^/.]+)?/?(.*)$ topusers.php?sort=$1&time=$
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I want the slash at the end of URL to be optional (URL works fine with or without it), how do I alter the RewriteRule? :)

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. Yes, it's accessible, but when I echo the variables, results are wrong.

Example links: `topusers.php?sort=post&time=all`,

With `^top/([^/.]+)?/?(.*)$ topusers.php?sort=$1&time=$2`, `sort = 'post'`, `time = 'all'`

With `^top/?([^/.]+)?/?(.*)$ topusers.php?sort=$1&time=$2`, `sort = 'users'`, `time = '.php'`

Comment: your link in that case should be `top/post/all` - not `topusers.php?sort=post&time=all`